# Get Certain Patterns of Chracters in a String in R

Tags: r

How can I in R predefine patterns that I would like to keep in a string a then in a column of a data frame?

```
g <- c("3+kk120", "3+1121", "1+170", "1+kk5")

# I want to get
c("3+kk", "3+1", "1+1", "1+kk")
```

[image]

Comment: What does 'pattern' mean?

Comment: Rooms in a flat + kitchen, kk == kitchen is part of a room, +1 == kitchen is a separate room.

Comment: the smallest flat: 1+1, 1+kk, 2+1, 2+kk, 3+1... 6+1, 6+kk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure if I understand you but, after replacing two digits (kk) into one (X) you can use `substr()`. Then you can replace back the previous one as follows,

```
sub("X","kk",substr(sub("kk","X",g),1,3))
```

gives,

```
# [1] "3+kk" "3+1"  "1+1"  "1+kk"
```

Comment: I tried and it works for my purpose so far :)